# a special case in convergence in distribution

Tags: probability

My homework asks me, it is given $X_{n},Y_n,n=1,2,\cdots$ which are 2 random variable sequences (may not be independent) defined on the same sample space, and $\mathcal{L}X_n\to\mathcal{L}X,\mathcal{L}Y_n\to\mathcal{L}c$ converge respectively in distribution, where c is a const, then the task is to show $\mathcal{L}(X_n+Y_n)\to\mathcal{L}(X+c)$ and $\mathcal{L}(X_nY_n)\to\mathcal{L}(cX)$, they also converge in distribution as $X_n$ and $Y_n$ do.

I know in general that $X_n,Y_n$ converge in distribution does not imply their sum and multiplication also do, but what special here is that $Y_n\to c$ a const, then ${\rm plim}_{n\to \infty}Y_n=c$ converges also in probability. But how can this help? The former claim warns me that general discussion may not work well here, but I fail to find any tricks relative to $Y_n$'s good property. Can you offer a hand? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If $X_n\stackrel{d}{\rightarrow}X$ and $Y_n\stackrel{d}{\rightarrow}c$ then $(X_n,Y_n)\stackrel{d}{\rightarrow}(X,c)$.  Apply then [the continuous mapping Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_mapping_theorem) to the random vector $Z_n=(X_n,Y_n)$ with the function $f(x,y)=x\,y$ to conclude that $f(X_n,Y_n)=X_n\,Y_n\stackrel{d}{\rightarrow}f(X,c)=c\,X$ (the same for $f(x,y)=x+y$).

Comment: But it seems that I can apply this method to prove the general case, viz Y_n can converge to another random variable Y, which we know is not always true?

Comment: @AlbertLiu I am not sure I totally understood your comment. In any case, the "general" case is not true, see This link for a counter example: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2732422/counter-example-for-the-slutsky-theorem

Comment: Sorry but what I want to ask here is what is wrong when I apply the method you show above to prove the general case? @AlmostSureUser

Comment: @AlbertLiu still I don't understand. In the "general case" what do you mean? You need to apply Slutsky's theorem here. Try to look at this link:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_of_convergence_of_random_variables#propB3
it could help